# Horizontally center text in <p> display: table-cell?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I'm trying to center the text horizontally, but it doesn't work. It seems to be because of the  display: table-cell
Would you know a work around? (note that I'm using bootstrap)

Thanks! > Codepen: http://codepen.io/goodux/pen/wgBCf

**html:**

```
<div class="feature">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star feature-icon"></span>
    <p class="feature-text text-center">
        Gather user's feedback and engineer's requirements.
    </p>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.feature {
    margin-bottom: 3.5em;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
span.feature-icon {
    background-color: #FA6900;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 3em;
    padding: .5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

p.feature-text {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 .5em 0 6.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 6em;
    display: table-cell;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: why make it `display:table-cell` ?

Comment: I want the feature-text to be vertically aligned. That's the solution I found searching in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `display:table-cell` to work correctly it needs to be inside a `display:table` element.

So, if you change the `.feature` rule to

```
.feature {
    margin-bottom: 3.5em;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
```

it will work as expected: http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/EDtCq

---

of course you could avoid using `display:table-cell` if it is not really needed. (*and in your example it looks like it is not..*)

Comment: Cool. I'll remmber that, since this will likely solve some other table-issues too, should I ever run into these.

Comment: Great works perfectly with your solution. What would you do to avoid display:table-cell?

Comment: @Goodux, i didn't notice the vertically aligned text.. If that is multiple lines then your solution is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`p {
text-align: center;
margin: auto
   }`
and why are you using `display:table-cell` ?

Comment: This wouldn't work. `margin: auto;` only centers things that have a specific width.

Comment: yep ! But I thought this user will set width and other thing as he wants. May be my answer is not helpful to him.

Comment: It doesn't work / This is all the code that exist. See it as a list and the text will not always have the same length.

Comment: Setting a fixed css width on a line of text is not a good idea - it forces you to rewrite styles when text is changed and completely erases all chances of a responsive design.